# Where is require_once REALLY looking?

Tags: php, environment-variables

I have 2 installations of php for 2 versions of joomla on my windows computer.

I get this error when executing an application:

> PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message
>   'require_once(Cache/Lite.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory' in
>   C:\xampp\apps\joomla\htdocs\libraries\joomla\cache\storage\cachelite.php:79

The line is

`require_once 'Cache/Lite.php';`

Well there IS this file called Lite.php in:

> C:\xampp\php\pear\Cache\Lite.php

I have a second php version installed, this might interfere. None the less, I removed the PATH entry of the second php version. I copied the folder to the second php installation, and I added the other php version to the path. Didn't help.

How can I find out where `require_once ''` is actually looking for?

Or how would you try to fix this?

Comment: `var_dump(get_include_path())`

Comment: i get an incomplete listing of the path. It says something like this:
string(722) "phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template;phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects;phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/phpunit/php-timer;phar://C:/ProgramData/"...

cutting the path of half way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the include path by:

```
<?php
echo get_include_path();
?>
```

If you need to change this, then you will need to modify your php.ini file or use [set_include_path()](https://www.php.net/set_include_path)

Remember to include your current include_path, when setting a new one:

```
<?php
$new_path = '/usr/lib/pear';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $new_path);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `echo getcwd() . "\n";` to know the current working directory of a script, that will answer your question. more info here [PHP Manual reference of getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing. The
>   include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this
>   is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
>   or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
>   current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be
>   ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the
>   parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.